# How execute command/script once after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos, gnome-terminal

On Centos6 I have this script and i need to execute it once after reboot in terminal.
How can i do this?
If I execute like `sh /path/to/script.sh` - all good, but if I add in `rc.local` (`sh /path/to/script.sh`) or `crontab` (`@reboot sh /path/to/script.sh`)- nothing happens.
I will be glad to any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'zenity --info --text="Msg1" --title="Text1..." --timeout=10
<some_command>
zenity --info --text="Msg2" --title="Text2..."  --timeout=10
<some_command>
zenity --info --text="Msg3" --title="Reboot..."  --timeout=10
sleep 1
exec bash'
```

Comment: /usr/share/gnome/autostart/script.desktop - doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Terminal is X application (GUI application). If you want to run any X application from cron, just "let him know" which display you're using since `cron` doesn't execute commands within your normal shell environment.

First of all detect which display is being used in your system:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

The output will be something like this:

```
:0
```

or

```
:1
```

Let's assume your `DISPLAY` variable is `:1`, then add to your script before command with GUI application `DISPLAY=:1` variable, i.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:1 gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'zenity --info --text="Msg1" --title="Text1..."  --timeout=10;<some_command>;zenity --info --text="Msg2" --title="Text2..."  --timeout=10;<some_command>;zenity --info --text="Msg3" --title="Reboot..."  --timeout=10;sleep 1; exec bash'
```

Besides `cron` there is another possibility in CentOS to run a something once at system startup - `rc-local` service mechanism. Create (if it isn't created yet) file:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/path/to/script.sh

exit 0
```

Put to the file all of the commands you wish to execute at startup.

Make the `rc.local` file executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Enable `rc-local` service and start it:

```
systemctl enable rc-local
systemctl start rc-local
```

Check if the service is running properly:

```
systemctl status rc-local
```